# Why does Pnumology come up with a lot of medical articles when looking for explanations?

Tags: explanation, graduate-school

I was doing some research on Pnumology philosophy (Theological [JP2] Philosophy class) that I plan to publish as one of my many books, and am getting a lot of medical articles, so it got me to wondering why I'm getting information on respiratory, and pulmonary care. What are some great explanations/examples for this philosophical school of thought?

Comment: Because [pneumology](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/pneumology), a.k.a. [pulmonology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pulmonology), is the study of the respiratory system, and "pnumology" is likely misspelled. Perhaps you had in mind [phenomenology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phenomenology_(philosophy)) or something else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The word you're looking for is [pneumatology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pneumatology), the study of the Holy Spirit. Pneumatology and (the somewhat archaic) pneumology share the same Greek root 'pneum', meaning breath or wind; the first usage is metaphorical (Spirit as the breath of life) while the second is literal (the medical study of the pulmonary organs). Confusing, yes...

Comment: Today I learned! Great factoid.